# Forcing fmincon to consider candidate solutions only from a specific set

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Is it possible to force MATLAB's fmincon to generate candidate points from a specific set of points that I supply? I ask this because if this were possible, it would greatly reduce computation complexity, and knock out a couple of constraints from the optimization.

*Edited to add more info:* Essentially, I'm looking for a set of points in a high dimension space which satisfy a particular function (belonging to that space), along with a couple of other constraints. The objective function minimizes the total length of the path formed by these points. Think generalized geodesic problem, attempted via non-linear optimization. While I manage to get near a solution while using fmincon, it is painfully slow and is prone to get stuck in local minima. I already have a sizeable set of data-points which satisfy this high-dimensional function, and have no compulsion that this new set of points not belong to this pre-existing set.

Comment: You can give a starting-point, but you can't limit the search to checking a finite set of values. In general this is the wrong approach (example: the discrete nature of this is what makes integer-programming NP-hard while linear-programming is within P; that might be unintuitive for some people). So if there is a small candidate set, you probably should not use fmincon; if you just got good start-values, call it many times with different starts (and limit iterations if you want).

Comment: I don't understand how a specific set of points would reduce computation complexity. To me, it sounds like adding another constraint. Maybe you would like to provide some more information about what you mean with "the set of points that you supply".

Comment: @nikaltipar The general idea is the following: instead of searching an infinite space, just search some discrete space where enumeration is enough. Or some other case: instead of 10^18 states, search 10^8 (random example) which is a valid strategy in discrete optimization. But you are of course right here. This logic does not apply in optimization theory (at least not in this case).

Comment: Depends what you mean by "a specific set of points". Is it a discrete set? In this case, the answer is clearly no as it disallows `fmincon` to carry out continously-valued optimization like computing gradients and step sizes and the like. In this case, you're probably trying so solve an integer optimization problem for which there are different methods. On the other hand, if you have some, say, compact set that you can describe by (possibly nonlinear) equality/inequality constraints the answer is yes, look into `nonlcon` options of `optimset`.

Comment: **typo**: I meant the nonlcon option of `fmincon`, not `optimset`.

Comment: Perhaps @sascha is right about the problem - I may be looking at the wrong way to approach it. I do not necessarily have to confine myself to fmincon; I'm open to other approaches as well. Essentially, I'm looking for a set of points in a high dimension space which satisfy a particular function (belonging to that space), along with a couple of other constraints. The objective function minimizes the total length of the path  formed by these points. While I manage to get near a solution  while using fmincon, it is painfully slow and is prone to get stuck in local minima.